# Javascript setInterval Going Crazy After A While

Tags: javascript, html

My goal with this was to create a div that runs through array items in rotation and also start immediately when the browser loads rather than wait to start. It starts working perfectly at first but after a while, it starts rotating between the array items crazy fast. Naturally that makes the browser slower. Why would this happen? How can I fix this?

```
    var arr = ["<h2 class='text-center'>For the best choice in compounding… Choose Alvix</h2>", "<h2 class='text-center'>We strive to become more self sufficient. <br>For you. For Alvix. For Life.</h2>", "<h2 class='text-center'>Alvix… Providers of Solutions</h2>"
    ];
    var i = 0;

    var timeout;
    function doStuff() {
        document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = arr[i];
        i++;
        if (i >= arr.length){
          i=0;
        }
        timeout = setInterval(doStuff,4000);
    }
    doStuff();
```

Comment: Because you're calling `setInterval` in `doStuff`. Change it to `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the setInterval out of the doStuff function.  Right now you are adding another 4 second timer every 4 seconds.  This will call `doStuff` immediately then every four seconds after.

```
    var arr = ["<h2 class='text-center'>For the best choice in compounding… Choose Alvix</h2>", "<h2 class='text-center'>We strive to become more self sufficient. <br>For you. For Alvix. For Life.</h2>", "<h2 class='text-center'>Alvix… Providers of Solutions</h2>"];
    var i = 0;

    var timeout;
    function doStuff() {
        document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = arr[i];
        i++;
        if (i >= arr.length){
          i=0;
        }            
    }
    timeout = setInterval(doStuff,4000);
    doStuff();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout` insteaded of `setInterval` you call your function every time it sets new interval so logical will find it go crazy,

you have 2 solution

1. To clear the interval with  `clearInterval`

   ```
    intrval = null
    function doStuff(){
        // logic...
        if(intrval) clearInterval(intrval);
        intrval = setInterval(doStuff, 4000);
     }

     doStuff();
   ```
2. Use `SetTimeout`

   ```
   function doStuff(){
   // logic...

   setTimeout(doStuff,400);
   } 
    doStuff();
   ```

Comment: Good answer, especially the 2nd example. A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is always a good idea, also. +1

Comment: JSFiddle is usually a terrible idea. Stackoverflow has supported [embedded live demos](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for over a year.

Comment: for me I test my code in browser console this is the most speed way I can depend on just press `F12`

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed The point is not for you (or anyone answering) to test their own code, it is to provide an environment for others to examine the code, see a demo, and play with the code in a working environment. Despite Quentin's knowledgeable comment, many of us still prefer the venerable [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to the new built-in system that StackOverflow recently implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You keep on setting new intervals each recurse. Set the interval outside of the function, so that when you call it, it's not reiterating its declaration.

```
function doStuff() {
    document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = arr[i];
    i++;
    if (i >= arr.length){
      i=0;
    }
}
var timeout = setInterval(doStuff,4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` calls a function **every** time period.

You are calling `setInterval` inside a that function, so every time period you start another loop.

You start with one interval. After 4 seconds you have 2. 4 seconds later each of those creates another one and you have 4. Then 8. Then 16.

Replace the line `doStuff();` with `timeout = setInterval(doStuff,4000);`.